# Certificate signed by unknown authority error in Jenkins pipeline with Kubernetes cluster deployment

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

When I am trying to deploy my spring boot microservice using Jenkins and Kubernetes I am getting the following error:

> Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")

My deployment.yaml file like the following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: spacestudysecurityauthcontrol-deployment
  labels:
    app: spacestudysecurityauthcontrol-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: spacestudysecurityauthcontrol-deployment
   template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spacestudysecurityauthcontrol-deployment
      annotations: 
        date: "+%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%y"
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: "regcred"
      containers:
       - name: spacestudysecurityauthcontrol-deployment-container
         image: spacestudymilletech010/spacestudysecurityauthcontrol:latest
         imagePullPolicy: Always
         ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8065
         readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8065
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
         livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8065
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 20
      nodeSelector:
          tenantName: tenant1
```

And my service like the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: spacestudysecurityauthcontrol-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8065
      targetPort: 8065
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
      nodePort: 31026
  selector:
    app: spacestudysecurityauthcontrol-deployment
```

Why is this error happening and how can I correct my implementation?

Comment: Hi Jacob. I wonder if I can offer some posting advice? It's worth remembering that the questions posted on this site are for long-term readers, not just immediate readers to help with a problem happening in the present. Thus we like to ensure that things are as readable as possible. When you post, there tends to be case/spelling/formatting errors, and I wonder if you could take a bit more care prior to submitting. That will save volunteer editors from a bit of work, and they surely have enough to do already.

Comment: Your questions sometimes come with the appearance that you'd like to have someone do it for you, and this is really not what Stack Overflow is for ("please correct my implementation", "can someone help me"). We encourage question authors here to find their own agency when dealing with a problem (e.g. "how can I correct my implementation", "what do I need to do") - that is how we all become better (and more self-sufficient) software engineers.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally means that the kubeconfig file used to authenticate to Kubernetes API server is having a CA certificate which is not able to validate the server certificate presented by Kubernetes API server. Double check if you are using correct kubeconfig file corresponding to the Kubernetes cluster you are trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

This is nicely explained inside Troubleshooting kubeadm [TLS certificate errors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#tls-certificate-errors)

> - Verify that the  `$HOME/.kube/config`  file contains a valid certificate, and regenerate a certificate if necessary. The certificates in a kubeconfig file are base64 encoded. The  `base64 --decode`  command can be used to decode the certificate and  `openssl x509 -text -noout`  can be used for viewing the certificate information.
> - Unset the  `KUBECONFIG`  environment variable using:
>
> ```
> unset KUBECONFIG
> ```
>
> Or set it to the default  `KUBECONFIG`  location:
>
> ```sh
>  export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
> ```
>
> - Another workaround is to overwrite the existing  `kubeconfig`  for the “admin” user:
>
> ```
> mv  $HOME/.kube $HOME/.kube.bak
> mkdir $HOME/.kube
> sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
> sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
> ```